# No sound python webbrowser

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a python web browser (uses firefox), but no sound works. What do I do?

I don't really know python, this is my first time. Maybe I should have started with something simpler.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.get('firefox').open_new_tab('https://experiments.cti.repl.co/browse/welcome.html')
```

I've Looked everywhere online and I can't find anything.

Here's the link to it: https://replit.com/@JakobSteele/ub-embed

Comment: _"Mabye I should have started with something simpler"_ Probably. Anyway, without any code, we can't help. Visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: this is all i have: import webbrowser
webbrowser.get('firefox').open_new_tab('https://experiments.cti.repl.co/browse/welcome.html')

Comment: I have it on replit

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I had to go into secrets on replit and turn on sound.

https://docs.replit.com/misc/playing-audio-replit